# While inserting data into Java array with while loop it doesnt stop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

Ive got a task where i have to insert random numbers into an array, if i put 0 as my number or if the array length has been achieved then the loop should stop, however i am stuck.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [] a1 = new int[100];


        int i = 1;
        boolean run = true;


        while(run){

            if(i < a1.length && i != 0){
                System.out.println("Insert number: (0-end)");
                a1[i] = scan.nextInt();

            }else if(i == 0){
                run = false;
            }

        }//while
```

Comment: or remove run variable and do if (i==0) break;

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to ask good questions. Espacially your question should include your expected and the actual behaviour. "I am stuck" is not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the while loop should be like

```
 while(true){
    System.out.println("Ange tal: (0-avsluta)");
    int temp = scan.nextInt();
    if(i == a1.length || temp == 0)
    {
        break;       
    }
    else
    {
        a1[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
 while(true){
```

To:

```
 while(run){
```

Answer (score 0):

remove else if branch and add:

```
if(i==0){
   run = false;
}
```

in if branch.

Answer (score 0):

try this (for loop here is more readable than while):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a1 = new int[100];
    for(int i=1; i< 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insert number: (0-end)");
        int nextInt = scan.nextInt();
        if(nextInt == 0) break;

        a1[i] = nextInt;
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as intended:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert size of array: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int index = 0;
    int value = -1;
    int[] a1 = new int[n]; //read the number of elements, because after you stop reading will be 0. If you leave it as int int[100] you might have all of them 0

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Input number: ");
        value = scan.nextInt();
        if (index != n && value != 0) {
            a1[index] = value;
            index++;
        } else
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Content of array a1 of size:"+n +" elements:");
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        System.out.println("a1["+i+"] = "+a1[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This while loop will not stop as you are not increasing the value of variable i.So it will be infinite loop... I am taking i as index variable of array a1...whereas the number which user is entering should be checked according to your question... I have edited the code please check now...

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int d=0;
        int [] a1 = new int[100];
             int i = 1;
            boolean run = true;
         while(run){
             if(i < a1.length && i != 0){
                    System.out.println("Ange tal: (0-avsluta)");
                    d = scan.nextInt();
                    if(d==0)
                       run=false;
                      a1[i]=d;
                     i++ 

            }//while

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] a1 = new int[100];


    int i = 0;



    while(true){

        if(i < a1.length){
            System.out.println("Insert number: (0-end)");
            a1[i] = scan.nextInt();
            if(a1[i]==0)
             break;
            else
             i++;
           }
          else
          break;
         }//while ends here
     }//End of main
```

If you are looking for the simplest way,I would suggest you to try this:-

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
 System.out.println("Enter the number,0 to exit");
 a1[i]=scan.nextInt();
 if(a[i]==0)
  break;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem thou is that i have to use a while loop :)

Answer (score 0):

try This code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            int [] a1 = new int[10];


            int i = 0;
            boolean run = true;
            int inputnum;

            while(run){
                 System.out.println("Ange tal: (0-avsluta)");
                inputnum =scan.nextInt();

                if(i<a1.length)
                {
                     if(inputnum==0)
                     {
                         run=false;
                         break;
                     }
                     else{

                         a1[i]=inputnum;
                         i++;
                     }

                }
                else
                {

                    System.out.println("Array is full");
                     run=false;
                     break;
                }



            }


            System.out.println("You are out of program");
        }
```